# C# - Threading tasks - best practices in Dotnet 4.x

Tags: c#, multithreading

In .NET 2.x i was using

```
 var SocketStart = new Thread(() => new WebSocketManager().Socket()); //to prepare websocket manager in background.
 SocketStart.Start(); //to start ws manager.
 var SocketStart2 = new Thread(() => new WebSocketManager().Socket2()); //to prepare websocket manager in background.
 SocketStart2.Start(); //to start ws manager.
 if(SomeDepedencyIsDead) //chacking if some stuff is working? 
   {
     SocketStart().Suspend(); //deprecaced
     SocketStart2().Suspend(); //deprecaced
      while(SomeDepedencyIsDead)
        {
           Wait();
        }
    SocketStart.Resume(); //deprecaced
    SocketStart2.Resume(); //deprecaced
    }
```

Now

> SocketStart().Suspend() is deprecaced && 
>   SocketStart().Resume() is deprecaced

And it gives me error

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Thread suspend is not supported on this platform.'

So, what is the best practice to pause, and start Threads? Should i use **new Thread(())** etc? Are there any better than **System.Threading** libraries to threading managment?

Comment: In your case use Thread.Sleep(interval) and specify the interval in millisecond so no need to use Wait() explicitly. After that Thread will start running

Comment: @SonalBorkar but its just example, i have 4 websockets and 6 other processes in this program. Should i do sleep in each one?

Comment: @SonalBorkar i edited my q.

Comment: Use of raw threads is discouraged in newer version of .NET. Use `Task`s and/or async code instead.

Comment: So, in this case no need for new Thread for each websockets. Since all are depend on one variable condition. You can directly use Thread.Sleep(interval) in while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below

```
var Socket1 =  new WebSocketManager(); //to prepare websocket manager in background.
 ... //to start ws manager.
 var Socket2 = new WebSocketManager(); //to prepare websocket manager in background.
 ... //to start ws manager.


      while(SomeDepedencyIsDead)
        {
           Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
```